# Quartus altera VHDL not getting output value

Tags: vhdl, quartus, intel-fpga

Ho to all.
I have a project for this semester using VHDL.
My goal is to make a code lock, which will set Pass signal to 1 if the code is right, and Pass 0 Error to 1 Siren to 0 if the code is wrong and 011 if i enter 3 separate wrong combinations.

Here is the code i am using and it shows undefined for wrong combination when simulating:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity sifrarnik is
port(
dig:in std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
enable:in std_logic;
outsig:out std_logic_vector(2 downto 0)
);
end sifrarnik;

architecture march of sifrarnik is
signal outtmp:std_logic_vector(2 downto 0);
--signal prev:std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
begin 
process (enable,dig)
variable temp:integer range 0 to 4;
begin
if (enable='0') then
case dig is
    when "1110" => 
        outtmp<="100";
        temp:=0;
    when others =>
        
        if(temp<3) then
            outtmp<="010";
            temp:=temp+1;
        elsif(temp=3) then
            outtmp<="011";
        end if;
        
    end case;

outsig<=outtmp;
else 
outtmp<="000";
end if;
end process;
end march;
```

Comment: VHDL has no Undefined value. 'U' means uninitialised, whereas 'X' means unknown. Which is presenting in your test? You provide no testbench code. I susgest you prove an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In my simulation i get no value for output signal, i get those lines like in a vwf file

Comment: Why don't you provide a screenshot of your simulator output?